# generateTreeList() in CakePhp with Element

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am facing some problems with TreeBehaviour::generateTreeList() with my cake 2.3;

I want to use the List generated by this function in an Element. 
So the Element uses $this->requestAction(); and the function returns $treelist.
But I get following Error where I embedded the Element:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'generateTreeList' at line 1
>
> SQL Query: generateTreeList
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
>
> Stack Trace
>
> CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php line 460 →
>   PDOStatement->execute(array) CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php
>   line 426 → DboSource->_execute(string, array)
>   CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php line 666 →
>   DboSource->execute(string, array, array)
>   CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php line 611 →
>   DboSource->fetchAll(string, array, array) CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php
>   line 799 → DboSource->query(string, array, AppModel)
>   APP\Controller\CategoriesController.php line 14 →
>   Model->__call(string, array)
>   APP\Controller\CategoriesController.php line 14 →
>   AppModel->generateTreeList() [internal function] →
>   CategoriesController->tree()
>   CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 486 →
>   ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(CategoriesController, array)
>   CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 187 →
>   Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest) CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php
>   line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(CategoriesController,
>   CakeRequest, CakeResponse) CORE\Cake\Core\Object.php line 104 →
>   Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse, array)
>   APP\View\Elements\categorieselement.ctp line 4 →
>   Object->requestAction(string) CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 945 →
>   include(string) CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 907 →
>   View->_evaluate(string, array) CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 1208 →
>   View->_render(string, array) CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 414 →
>   View->_renderElement(string, array, array)
>   APP\View\Posts\view.ctp line 197 → View->element(string)
>   CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 945 → include(string)
>   CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 907 → View->_evaluate(string, array)
>   CORE\Cake\View\View.php line 471 → View->_render(string)
>   CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php line 948 → View->render(null,
>   null) CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php line 194 → Controller->render()

I have verfied 100 times beeing very close to the manual regarding the function and everything. I have checked $actsAs beeing spelled correctly.
If I don't use generateTreeList() but just find('list') I get output as expected.

Where is my fault? Is TreeBehaviour not usable with with Elements?

Thanks for any Help.

**Update after request "Show your related code as well":**

Posts/view.ctp:

```
... 
echo '<hr><br><h3>Other Categories</h3>'; echo
$this->element('categorieselement'); 
...
```

Elements/categorieselement.ctp:
(I just didn't put more on printing the result than the debug function right now. First the result should work, than I will care about displaying.)

```
<?php 
$trees = $this->requestAction('/categories/tree');
debug($trees); 
?>
```

CategoriesController:
Just to add: Even if I add more Options to the generateTreeList-Function, the Error remains the same.
If I replace "generateTreeList();" by "find();" I get a result displayed in posts/view and not an Error. So the element and returning $data is working.

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function tree() {
        $data = $this->Category->generateTreeList();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Category Model:

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Tree');

}
```

Comment: Show your related code as well.

Comment: The requested Code is provided in the question.

Comment: Try not to use requestAction() and pass the data down from the controller instead, e.g. via component.

Comment: The code seems to be correct, however "SQL Query: generateTreeList" means that the behavior is not loaded for that model instance. The error is the default that happens with a behavior can't be accessed. Try debug($this->Category-Behaviors->loaded('Tree')); before calling generateTreeList(), if it return false try calling Behaviors->load('Tree');

Comment: How? Is there somewhere an tutorial for component?

Comment: @burzum Thank you a lot. I added an If to load it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, if that works it doesn't mean it's a good solution. Actually you should figure out why your model is not initializing the behavior in the first place. It is likely that there are other things not working right as well. debug(get_class($this->Category)); and see if it says "Category" or "AppModel" or "Model". I suspect that you're not getting the right model instance.

Comment: Figure out why its not getting an instance of the Category model class then. Nothing you add to you Category model will work right now because $this->Category is an instance of AppModel and not Category. You understand the root of the issue?

Comment: I understand he consequenzes. But I dont't know where to start checking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Burzum solved it (see Comment)
He diagnosed, the Tree-Behaviour would not be loaded and I should check for it.

I added this code into the function tree in the controller, to be 100% shure:

```
if($this->Category->Behaviors->loaded('Tree') != true){
    $this->Category->Behaviors->load('Tree');
}
```

Comment: **No I did not this is a symptom not the cause!** This code was just for debugging to see if the behavior is loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try these link mention below

- http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-TreeBehavior.html#_generateTreeList
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::generateTreeList

Comment: I used these contents for searching the fault. I cant find there any details why my generateTreeList in an Element shouldn't be working.